# Table data Scraping using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in0x0.png)

Why i'm not getting the all rows while extracting the table data using BeautifulSoup in Python ?

Link to website - http://www.fao.org/3/x0490e/x0490e04.htm

```
table1_rows = table1.find_all('tr')

for tr in table1_rows:
td = tr.find_all('td')
row = [i.text for i in td]
print(row)
```

[Output of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E19Tl.png)

```
print(row)
row = [item.strip() for item in row if str(item)]
row
```

[But i'm getting this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uopu1.png)

After doing some changes

```
for tr in table1_rows:
td = tr.find_all('td')
row = [i.text for i in td]
row = [item.strip() for item in row if str(item)]
print(row)
```

Then also i'm not getting the output. Can anyone please help me?
When i'm printing the row variable out of the loop then i'm not getting the output ?

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BSh1.png)

Comment: post your code pls and link to url you want to webscrap. pictures of codes are not as helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
row = [item.strip() for item in row if str(item)]
```

should sit inside the `for tr in table1_rows` loop:

```
for tr in table1_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    row = [item.strip() for item in row if str(item)]
    print(row)
```

**Edit:**
To collect all rows:

```
all_rows=[]
for tr in table1_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    row = [item.strip() for item in row if str(item)]
    all_rows.append(row)

for row in all_rows:
    print(row)
```

**Edit 2:**
If the ultimate aim is to get the table data into a dataframe, then that's a one liner job (this *replaces* the for loop approach):

```
df=pd.read_html(url)[0]
```

You obviously need to import pandas first:

```
import pandas as pd
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: After doing this, when i give print(row) command inside the for loop it prints the desired output of all the rows.    But when i give print(row) command in a new cell, then it is only printing the last row of the table. i have attached the output in the question above.

Comment: What is the output you would expect?

Comment: in comments, we can't upload images. so i have uploaded the screenshot in the end of the question that i'm expecting in the row variable. can you please check in the question

Comment: Ah so all table rows then. For that you need to collect all rows in a single variable. See my edit.

Comment: i'm converting this all_rows variable to df. But i'm not getting a proper dataframe.

Comment: You should have mentioned that's what you are trying to do :). See Edit 2. That one line replaces the `for` loop.

Comment: Kindly check, i have added EDIT-3

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are at the end of the loop when in the next jupyter block. That table is kinda weirdly formatted too so I went and made this to get the data and column headers as a nested dict list:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://www.fao.org/3/x0490e/x0490e04.htm'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

table = soup.find('table')

def clean(text):
    return text.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '').replace('  ', '').strip()

# get the column headers
headers = [clean(col.text)
           for col in table.find_all('tr')[1].find_all('td')]
# set the first column to 'name' because it is blank
headers.insert(0, 'name') 

# get the data rows and zip them to the column headers
data = [{col[0]: clean(col[1].text)
         for col in zip(headers, row.find_all('td'))}
        for row in table.find_all('tr')[2::]]

data_list = [headers] + [list(row.values()) for row in data]

# print to list of lists
pprint.pprint(data_list)
# pretty print to json
import json
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
# print to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
[['name', 'mm day-1', 'm3 ha-1 day-1', 'l s-1 ha-1', 'MJ m-2 day-1'],
 ['1 mm day-1', '1', '10', '0.116', '2.45'],
 ['1 m3 ha-1 day-1', '0.1', '1', '0.012', '0.245'],
 ['1 l s-1 ha-1', '8.640', '86.40', '1', '21.17'],
 ['1 MJ m-2 day-1', '0.408', '4.082', '0.047', '1']]
[
    {
        "name": "1 mm day-1",
        "mm day-1": "1",
        "m3 ha-1 day-1": "10",
        "l s-1 ha-1": "0.116",
        "MJ m-2 day-1": "2.45"
    },
    {
        "name": "1 m3 ha-1 day-1",
        "mm day-1": "0.1",
        "m3 ha-1 day-1": "1",
        "l s-1 ha-1": "0.012",
        "MJ m-2 day-1": "0.245"
    },
    {
        "name": "1 l s-1 ha-1",
        "mm day-1": "8.640",
        "m3 ha-1 day-1": "86.40",
        "l s-1 ha-1": "1",
        "MJ m-2 day-1": "21.17"
    },
    {
        "name": "1 MJ m-2 day-1",
        "mm day-1": "0.408",
        "m3 ha-1 day-1": "4.082",
        "l s-1 ha-1": "0.047",
        "MJ m-2 day-1": "1"
    }
]
              name mm day-1 m3 ha-1 day-1 l s-1 ha-1 MJ m-2 day-1
0       1 mm day-1        1            10      0.116         2.45
1  1 m3 ha-1 day-1      0.1             1      0.012        0.245
2     1 l s-1 ha-1    8.640         86.40          1        21.17
3   1 MJ m-2 day-1    0.408         4.082      0.047            1
```

**My output of df**

```
     MJ m-2 day-1 l s-1 ha-1 m3 ha-1 day-1 mm day-1             name
    0         2.45      0.116            10        1       1 mm day-1
    1        0.245      0.012             1      0.1  1 m3 ha-1 day-1
    2        21.17          1         86.40    8.640     1 l s-1 ha-1
    3            1      0.047         4.082    0.408   1 MJ m-2 day-1
```

Comment: how to convert this "data" variable to a cleaned table ?

Comment: what do you mean by cleaned table? Pandas?

Comment: added list output and pandas

Comment: Why i'm not getting the same df output you are getting

Comment: not sure, if you copy this exact code and run it, you should get the same output

Comment: Looks like your output df data is the same, just with columns in a different order

Comment: As in our output we are not getting headers while scraping,  How can we add headers to get a structured table

Comment: that table has a two-part header with some header groups, I'm not sure how you would convert that to 'data' tabular form, the best option for grouped objects may be a dictionary for each header group

Comment: How can i get other tables from the website?

Comment: you can do `soup.find_all('table')`